# dc.js seriesChart doesn't seem to work with the rangeChart

Tags: dc.js

I have been trying to get a rangeChart filter with brushes to work with a seriesChart.  The main chart does not seem to respond to the filter.  I took the series.html example and added a rangeChart on jsFiddle, [series-with-range-example](http://jsfiddle.net/peterth/j3koz28f/2/)

```
var chart = dc.seriesChart("#test");
var overviewChart = dc.seriesChart("#test-overview");
var ndx, runDimension, runGroup, overviewRunDimension, overviewRunGroup;

var experiments = d3.csv.parse(d3.select("pre#data").text());

  ndx = crossfilter(experiments);
  runDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return [+d.Expt, +d.Run]; });
  overviewRunDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return [+d.Expt, +d.Run]; });
  runGroup = runDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return +d.Speed; });
  overviewRunGroup = overviewRunDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return +d.Speed; });

  chart
    .width(768)
    .height(480)
    .chart(function(c) { return dc.lineChart(c).interpolate('basis'); })
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,20]))
    .brushOn(false)
    .yAxisLabel("Measured Speed km/s")
    .xAxisLabel("Run")
    .clipPadding(10)
    .elasticY(true)
    .dimension(runDimension)
    .group(runGroup)
    .mouseZoomable(true)
    .rangeChart(overviewChart)
    .seriesAccessor(function(d) {return "Expt: " + d.key[0];})
    .keyAccessor(function(d) {return +d.key[1];})
    .valueAccessor(function(d) {return +d.value - 500;})
    .legend(dc.legend().x(350).y(350).itemHeight(13).gap(5).horizontal(1).legendWidth(140).itemWidth(70));
  chart.yAxis().tickFormat(function(d) {return d3.format(',d')(d+299500);});
  chart.margins().left += 40;

  overviewChart
    .width(768)
    .height(100)
    .chart(function(c) { return dc.lineChart(c).interpolate('basis'); })
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,20]))
    .brushOn(true)
    .xAxisLabel("Run")
    .clipPadding(10)
    .dimension(overviewRunDimension)
    .group(overviewRunGroup)
    .seriesAccessor(function(d) {return "Expt: " + d.key[0];})
    .keyAccessor(function(d) {return +d.key[1];})
    .valueAccessor(function(d) {return +d.value - 500;})

  dc.renderAll();
```

It demonstrates the problem I am having.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I went a ways down the path of trying to make this work but although I did get something working, I decided it's probably too hacky to be helpful. The original issue is https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/390. Basically dc.js does not have a concept of multiple charts sharing the same selection, and there are various half-hearted hacks in the code which try to cover this up.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: *The issue was fixed in dc.js v3, since the composite chart now owns the brush and filters the children correctly. The below is only relevant to dc.js v2.*

Well, I got it working, sort of, with some ugly code. The general problem here is that dc.js charts don't have a way to share brushes between instances, so composite brushing in general (where there are a lot of instances in one) doesn't work very well.

In particular, [here is the issue for series charts](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/390). And for anyone else who is interested, the [even-more specific issue of focus-series charts is here](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/479).

If you just want to get something working, here is a pretty horrible workaround I came up with.

First, one thing that is not a workaround. You always want to use the same dimension and group for a focus and range chart. This is because you don't want them to filter each other: they are views on the same data and logically share a brush.

So I did:

```
overviewChart
  .dimension(runDimension)
  .group(runGroup)
```

Someone at some point attempted to solve the composite-filtering problem by not filtering the composite chart, but passing the filter down to its children. So if you capture the filter event on one of the children and do what a range chart would normally do when it's filtered, you'll get the behavior you want.

Here is where it gets really ugly:

```
overviewChart
  .chart(function(c,_,_,i) {
  var chart = dc.lineChart(c).interpolate('basis');
  if(i===0)
    chart.on('filtered', function (chart) {
        if (!chart.filter()) {
            dc.events.trigger(function () {
                overviewChart.focusChart().x().domain(overviewChart.focusChart().xOriginalDomain());
                overviewChart.focusChart().redraw();
            });
        } else if (!rangesEqual(chart.filter(), overviewChart.focusChart().filter())) {
            dc.events.trigger(function () {
                overviewChart.focusChart().focus(chart.filter());
            });
        }
    });
  return chart;
  })
```

the `on('filtered', ...)` stuff is copied pretty much wholesale out of the coordinate grid chart implementation of rangechart.

["Working" fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3koz28f/19/). I put "working" in quotes because [there is an issue where points on the boundary of a chart do not get rendered](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/949), which leads to absurd transitions here.

But it sort of works.

Comment: "Sort of works" is correct @Gordon. I played around with the brushes a little in the forked jsFiddle mentioned above; often when the mouse button is released, the zoom on the focusChart reverts to not having a filter (i.e, is not zoomed at all)  Sometimes is works correctly.  But, I even got the brush filtering into a state where the lines on the focusChart were not drawn at all.  This is just to say that the work-around problems are not just related to "absurd" transitions (although I did see those as well)

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about another problem I was seeing when I tried this out last week. Let me try to recall what that was and update my answer if I can find a solution. This is bad, bad stuff and at this point it might make more sense to implement it outside of the range / focus stuff which is just a tiny, hardly thought-out feature.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon.  I will try to debug it a little as well.

Comment: So @Gordon, it seems that the chart.on('filtered') is getting called for mouseMove events.  When you move the mouse into the jsFiddle chart frame the filter logic is getting executed TWICE.  The first time the chart gets redrawn with no filter.  The second time the filter is applied (if there is one).

Comment: Yeah,  there is an antipattern where some dc.js components think it's necessary to clear the current filter before setting a new one, and they do this in a way that creates a lot of side effects. Yesterday I determined that there's no way around this one (coming from the compositeChart) without an internal fix. It's safe and shouldn't break other stuff. I'll try to test it later today.

Comment: So I am assuming that the mouseMove event should not have caused the chart to be redraw (not to mention, twice).  Is that correct @Gordon ?

Comment: BTW, in my original comment I mentioned that sometime the focus chart is not drawn.  That seems to be because the brushes can be moved so close together in the overviewChart that there are no data points to display in the focusChart.  Interesting question is how to handle that case more gracefully

Comment: No, by default the brush and filter do change while the mouse is moving - this is exactly the same behavior [you can see on the main page](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/). The issue is that it's filtering twice per change, once with a null filter, which is inefficient and sometimes it gets caught in that in-between state. I guess the best way to deal with a tiny brush is to limit the minimum size (and this would work if we fix that off-edge points problem I mentioned).

Comment: Basically right now because of the [#949](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/949) you have to have at least two points selected. Which is very stupid, but that's technical debt for you. (Another maintainer implemented a lot of stuff very quickly, some of it very good but also causing some problems.)

Comment: Okay, I pushed a fix for that double-filter glitch, and it seems to work fine except when you brush less than two points. Fiddle now works since it was pointing to master, added [an example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/range-series.html) too.